# How to keep only certain columns and drop the remaining based on a criteria from a different data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm new to this and trying to learn multi-variable linear regression analysis and here with 10 variables. I'm trying to update /create a new data frame with only columns only whose VIF is less than 5.

This is the code I used to create a `DataFrame` with my VIF values. X1 is the `DataFrame`with the data for the same variables

```
vif =pd.DataFrame()
vif['Variane inflation factor'] = [variance_inflation_factor(X1.values, i) for i in range(X1.shape[1])]
vif['feature names'] = X1.columns


output:
    Variance inflation factor   feature names
0   314.550195                 const
1   9.807879                   gdp_growth
2   2.430057                   gross_capital_formation
3   25.759263                  pop_growth
4   26.174368                  birth_rate
5   1.633079                   broad_money_growth
6   2305.724583                final_consum_growth
7   32.527332                  gov_final_consum_growth
8   3.796420                   gross_cap_form_growth
9   2129.093634                hh_consum_growth
10  2.800008                   unemployment
```

So, I'm trying to figure out how to have my new `DataFrame` with variables whose VIF value is less than 5. Using `df.loc` with the actual variable name might work, but wanted to extend this to a problem with more number of variables where using the actual variable names might be difficult.
Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. No need to use `loc` to filter a dataframe based on values in a column -

```
vif_filtered = vif[vif['Variane inflation factor']<5]
```

If you want to filter the dataframe X1 based on these features then -

```
cols = list(vif_filtered['feature_names'].unique())
X1_filtered = X1[cols]
```

Comment: Is there a performance improvement by eliminated `.loc`?

Comment: None what so ever, it's just unnecessary code but has the exact same implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response@AkshaySehgal. I want to be able to filter the 'X1' data frame only with these columns in the 'vif_filtered'. In this case, filter the column for the variables with the index 2,5,8,10.

Comment: Yes, isnt that what the output of the above code is? You are left with vif_filtered which has index 2,5,8,10 rows only.

Comment: edited my answer to your requirement. if it solves your problem, do mark it as the current answer

Comment: Yes, vif_filtered gives out those rows. X1 is the dataframe which has all the data for these 10 variables (shape of X1 is 803 x 10 ). I'm looking on how to update X1 for only these variables (So, the updated X1 data frame will be of shape803 x 4)

Comment: See my updated answer I have included that. X1_filtered is your dataframe with those 4 features.